# A CNN while working for a while crashes with no error in Keras and on a Centos 7 Cluster

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, keras, cluster-computing, centos7

I have written a Keras code with using the ResNet50 architecture which is available in Keras pretrained models. My training dataset is huge (70K 512*512 images). The network can be trained with no problem for a while (sometimes a week, sometimes for two weeks, and it can happen on different epochs); but it suddenly crashes with no error.
The code, dataset, and system remain intact while the code working.
Also, I am saving the weights for each epoch and printing the log of training for each batch which does not show any failure.

I run everything on a reliable cluster and I have talked with our cluster admin; he mentioned there is no error recorded on the cluster side. Since this has happened a couple of time, he suggested me to contact you to check if you have seen such behavior from Keras models?
If not, can you please help us if there is any way in the Keras training procedure to check the followings:

stack size
working set size
number of open files
the name of each function or sub-routine as it is called -- to see if the program always exits from the same place
internal information about the variables & data structures within your program
I can print all these from python but I do not know how to do that while my network is being trained.

Can anyone help with this?

The code works and it suddenly crashes with no error, neither on the cluster side and on the code log or saved files.

This is my system info:
Have I written custom code (as opposed to using example directory): The code does training a Resnet using Keras pretrained model.
OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04): Centos (Cluster)
TensorFlow backend (yes / no): Yes
TensorFlow version: tensorflow-gpu==1.12.0
Keras version: Keras==2.2.4
Python version: 3.6
CUDA/cuDNN version: 9.0
GPU model and memory: P100, 12GB

Comment: What queueing system are you using? maybe slurm? the stderr is usually output to a different file, depending on how your job is queued. Maybe there is an error message and you are not seeing it.

Comment: It Sun Grid Engine (SGE). The admin told me that there was no error in the job causing the failure; also, there was no sign of failure as the job sounds to be performed and done successfully (returning 0).